# Looking for a better code pattern to implement user input validation in Python Cmd implementatiion

Tags: python

I am a new with Python (very experienced in Java) and I am coding an application using the ***cmd*** package.   Implementations of Cmd class will create methods like the one below (pattern "do_*") to respond to user input.

I have one such method that looks like the following.  In particular in the spirit of DRY I don't like having to repeat  the same print/return sequence 3 times.

Is there a more Pythonesque code pattern that would be more elegant or have I done it correctly?

```
def do_addvlan(self, arg):
    'Add a VLAN.  Usage:  addvlan <number> <name>'
    args = arg.split()
    if len(args) < 1:
        print("Err: VLAN needs to be 0 to 4095")
        return
    try:
        vlan = int(args[0])
    except ValueError:
        print("Err: VLAN needs to be 0 to 4095")
        return
    if vlan < 0 or vlan > 4095:
        print("Err: VLAN needs to be 0 to 4095")
        return
    print("OK I will add VLAN %d" % vlan)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question's somewhat vague about what how `vlan` gets "added", but you could use a class decorator to add `do_VLAN` sorts of methods to a `cmd.Cmd` subclass similar to what you command does in the example code. Passing explicit arguments to a decorator requires essentially writing a *decorator factory* which creates a regular decorator using the parameters passed and returns it.

Here's what I'm talking about:

```
import cmd

def add_cmd(attr, kind, lo, hi, doc=""):
    def decorator(cls):
        def do_cmd(self, args):
            args = args.split()
            if len(args) != 1:
                print("Err: {} needs one argument".format(attr))
                return
            try:
                value = kind(args[0])
            except ValueError:
                print("Err: {} argument needs to be of type {}".format(attr, kind))
                return
            if not (lo <= value <= hi):
                print("Err: {} argument needs to be range {} to {}".format(attr, lo, hi))
                return
            print("Adding attribute {} = {}".format(attr, value))
            setattr(self, attr, value)
            self.__dict__.setdefault("_added", []).append(attr)
        # override method's special attributes
        func_name = "do_" + attr
        setattr(do_cmd, "__name__", func_name)
        setattr(do_cmd, "__module__", cls.__module__)
        if doc: setattr(do_cmd, "__doc__", doc)
        setattr(cls, func_name, do_cmd)  # add method created to class
        return cls
    return decorator

if __name__ == '__main__':
    @add_cmd("VLAN", int, 0, 4095, "Adds VLAN attribute between 0-4095")
    @add_cmd("WEIGHT", float, 0, 1000, "Adds WEIGHT attribute between 0-1000")
    class MyCmd(cmd.Cmd):
        prompt = "MyCmd> "

        def do_SHOW(self, line):
            "Shows what attributes have been added so far"
            added = getattr(self, "_added", None)
            if not added:
                print("No attributes have been added yet.")
            else:
                print("Added attributes:")
                for attr in added:
                    print("  {}: {}".format(attr, getattr(self, attr)))

        def do_EOF(self, line):
            print("Exiting")
            return True

    MyCmd().cmdloop()
```

This is the output generated from running it in console session demonstrating that it works:

```
>python "looking-for-a-better-code-pattern-to-implement-user-input-validation.py"

MyCmd> help

Documented commands (type help <topic>):
========================================
SHOW  VLAN  WEIGHT  help

Undocumented commands:
======================
EOF

MyCmd> help VLAN
Adds VLAN attribute between 0-4095
MyCmd> help WEIGHT
Adds WEIGHT attribute between 0-1000
MyCmd> help SHOW
Shows what attributes have been added so far
MyCmd> VLAN 42
Adding attribute VLAN = 42
MyCmd> WEIGHT 3.1415
Adding attribute WEIGHT = 3.1415
MyCmd> SHOW
Added attributes:
  VLAN: 42
  WEIGHT: 3.1415
MyCmd> ^Z
Exiting

>
```

Comment: I omitted the business logic in my question because I thought it was irrelevant.  However your idea is interesting so I think I will explore it.  Thanks.

Comment: In the code in my example I arbitrarily chose to make the commands add an attribute with the corresponding command name to the class instance, which added some extraneous complexity. Frankly, usage of the `cmd` module is very rare — yours is the first reference and use of I've ever encountered.

Comment: Actually it would probably been better to make `_added` a dictionary instead of a list to prevent duplicate entries — but that's not a terribly important detail in a toy example.